# How to change chrome cast device volume using android seekbar

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, chromecast

I want to change chromecast device volume using my application seekbar. 
here is my code for onProgressChanged of seekbar

```
 try {
            if (mCastSession != null && mCastSession.isConnected()) {
                mCastSession.setVolume(mVolumeSeekbar.getProgress()*vol*3.33);
                mMediaRouter.getSelectedRoute().requestSetVolume((int) Math.ceil(mVolumeSeekbar.getProgress()*vol*3.33));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The above code work but only set 0(zero) and high(full volume) not intermediate volume.

Please let me know how can I will change chrome cast volume.

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't reach the "route" directly; if you are using Cast SDK, you shoud just use that to change volume (i.e. remove the second line that is setting the volume). Then, make sure you are using the right scale; `CastSession#setVolume()` takes an argument between 0 and 1 and I *guess* your max set by your progressbar is beyond that, so scale it appropriately to make sure you remain between 0 and 1.